# Flipper + Flutter error : Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: xcode, flutter, flipper, fbflipper

I integrate [Flipper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flipperkit) in my Flutter app, it worked very well in both Android and iOS emulator and real-devices,but I had a problem here : I can't archive build on xCode to export **ipa** file.

`flutter_flipperkit: 0.0.22`

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "CKAnalyticsListenerHelpers::GetReusedNodes(NSObject*)", referenced from:
      +[SKComponentLayoutWrapper newFromRoot:parentKey:] in libFlipperKit.a(SKComponentLayoutWrapper.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Maybe you should add that to the github repo of the library providing a reproducible repository to test on

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to occur on [flutter_flipperkit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flipperkit) 0.0.23 as well. One way to solve this issue is to modify the Podfile of your Flutter project's iOS build. I suggest trying out this [workaround](https://github.com/leanflutter/flutter_flipperkit/issues/27#issuecomment-752720161) after upgrading to the latest version of the plugin..